# Radio button not visible to android in android fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am fetch data using json and set my spinner and I am also want to add radio button in my operator spinner but radio button not visible and not working I want visible button some Ids but its not visible.

**MyXML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rount_corner1"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:hint="Enter Mobile number"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/prenumber"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="Enter Recharge Amount"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/rechergpre"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/operator_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:prompt="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                   </Spinner>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="38dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/_TopUp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TopUp "
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Special"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Special(2G,3G,SMS,VOICE )"

            />

    </RadioGroup>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/prepaid_submit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Mycode in Fragment**

```
 private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    MyApplication myOpt = (MyApplication)getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        json_data = new ArrayList<Json_Data>();
        datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
        oprList = new ArrayList<String>();
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://www.example.com");
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonobject);
        try {
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Json_Data opt_code = new Json_Data();
                opt_code.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                opt_code.setId(jsonobject.optString("ID"));
                json_data.add(opt_code);
                datalist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                oprList.add(jsonobject.getString("ID"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.operator_spinner);
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        datalist));
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                      // get Operaotor cod in opt_code field

                        String opt_code = oprList.get(position);
                        String selectedItem = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            Log.d("Selected operator is==", "======>" + selectedItem);
                            Log.d("Selected Value is======", "========>" + position);
                            Log.d("Selected ID is======", "========>" + opt_code);
                        if(opt_code=="8" || opt_code=="14"|| opt_code=="35"||opt_code=="36"||opt_code=="41"||opt_code=="43")
                        {
                            _RadioGroup = (RadioGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                            _RadioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mySpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                    int selectedId = _RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                                    // find the radiobutton by returned id
                                    RadioButton _RadioSex = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(selectedId);

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            _RadioSex.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });

               }
                            String user1 = myOpt.setOperator(opt_code);
                            String opt_name = myOpt.setOpt_provider(selectedItem);


                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
```

Image like:

[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: can you please check that your list datalist contains data or not ?

Comment: thank to reply yes i did

Comment: mySpinner check its setOnItemSelectedListener and setOnClickListener on onPostExecute

Comment: @HirenPatel i am updated whole code Please see

Comment: What is your parent layout?

Comment: @PiyushGupta see now i am updating my xml also

Answer (score 0):

Chenge xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/operator_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textAlignment="center" >
</Spinner>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="38dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/_TopUp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TopUp " />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Special"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Special(2G,3G,SMS,VOICE )" />
</RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for replying but i want to display radio button some operators